# Codeigniter dumps Model-Class when Loading a model

Tags: php, codeigniter

got some strange behavior with Codeigniter (2.1.4):

All the time I insert a model

```
$this->load->model('Enrollment');
```

The Page doesnt get rendered anymore, but i get the content of the class.
Dont get what I did to get this behavior. Was just inserting the Database Credentials.
If I dont load the model, all works fine...
Didnt touch anything besides config.php for BaseURL and Key and database.php for credentials...

Modelclass:

```
class Enrollment extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

class Anmeldung extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Enrollment');
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('days','Tage','callback_checkDays');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('checkDays', 'Es muss mindestens 1 Tag ausgewählt werden.');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_name','Unternehmen','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('participant_firstname','Vorname','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('participant_lastname','Nachname','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('participant_departement','Funktion','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('participant_email','Email','required|valid_email');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_address_street','Straße','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_address_zipcode','Postleitzahl','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_address_city','Straße','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_address_country','Land','required');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('agreement','Datenschutz','callback_checkAgreement');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('checkAgreement', 'Bitte stimmen Sie unseren Teilnahme Bedingungen zu.');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('anmeldung');
    }
    else
    {
        return "true";
    }
}

function checkDays() {
    $data = $this->input->post('days');
    //mindestens ein feld muss true sein
    if($data[0] == 1 || $data[1] == 1 || $data[2] == 1) return true;
    else return false;
}

function checkAgreement() {
    $data = $this->input->post('agreement');
    if($data[0] == 0 || $data[1] == 0) return false;
    else return true;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: have you got <?php on first line of the model script?

Comment: what is the error msg you are getting? and also Where are you using Enrollment model in your controller?

Comment: ... I dont want to tell you that the <?php was missing... too embarassing ;)